Woocommerce identifier that carries over from cart to order?
Is there any sort of ID or something that carries over from the user's session into the saved order? I'm working on something custom that involves saving some info from the cart session, and then updating it when the order goes through; I need some sort of value that is present in both the cart session and the final order.
I thought "_cart_hash" would work, but it's showing the same hash value no matter the browser, IP location, etc. when testing.
